# Is Psalm 74:13 prophetic of the future or a reference to the past? Was that part of the process of taming the chaotic abyss?

Tags: tehilim-psalms, creation, genesis-bereishith

Is Psalm 74:13 prophetic of the future or a reference to the past? Was that part of the process of taming the chaotic abyss?:

> Psalm 74:13You crumbled the sea with Your might; You shattered the heads of the sea monsters on the water.

https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16295/jewish/Chapter-74.htm#v13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tehillim 74:13, Asaf refers to Egyptians as תַ֝נִּינִים “crocodiles”  crushed during Yam Suf crossing. - same sarcastic title used by Yechezkel in Ezekiel 29:3 מִצְרַ֔יִם הַתַּנִּים֙ (alluding to Egyptian army’s faith in Sobek). * This is an example of political satire representing Egyptians in the image of their god.

Comment: Okay, so he is alluding to Egypt, rather than the abyss?

Comment: @Ruminator the word "abyss" is not used in Tehillim 74:13, and so why would the "abyss" be alluded to? Otherwise, how do you define "abyss" and to which word in Tehillim 74.13 are you connecting it to?